# Is there any way to resolve useRef issue. React Hook useRef not working properly in NextJS app

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

When ever I am refreshing the page, the Ref value showing null. Because of this the if condition blocks are not working.

I tried to edit the `useRef` values but not able to give other than null. If I am doing console log to the `myDivRef.current` I getting "Ref: null". Not able to figure out the exact issue because of the `useEffect` running every first render. The `useEffect` will run once again because of the state and  `fetchMore` function I mentioned in dependency array.

```
function DisplayLoadMore() {
  
  const [state, setState] = useState(0);
  const { loading, error, data, fetchMore} = useQuery(GET_DATA,{
    variables: {
      cursor: 0,
      limit: 40
    },
  });
  const myDivRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleScroll = () => {
      if (myDivRef.current) {
        console.log("True");
        const isAtBottom =
          myDivRef.current.scrollTop + myDivRef.current.clientHeight ===
          myDivRef.current.scrollHeight;


        if (isAtBottom) {
          console.log("Hit bottom");
          setState((state) => {
            return state + 40;
          });
          fetchMore({
            variables: { cursor: state, limit: 40 },
          });
        }
      }
    };

    if (myDivRef.current) {
      myDivRef.current.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    }

    return () => {
      if (myDivRef.current) {
        myDivRef.current.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
      }
    };
  }, [fetchMore, state]);

  try{ 
    if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
    if (error) return <p>Error!!!</p>;
    if (!data) return <p>Not found</p>;   
  }catch (error: any){
    console.error('An error occurred:', console.error(error));
  }finally{
    console.log('...'); 
  }
  
  return (
    <div ref={myDivRef} style={{ overflowY: 'scroll', height: '700px' }}>
      {data.pagedbs.map(({ id, name }: { id: number; name: string }) => (
        <div key={id}>
          <p>{name}</p>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
  

}
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div >  
    <DisplayLoadMore/>      
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `data` to the dependency array.

This will trigger the useEffect to call whenever the data object changes, which in turn means if should trigger after the useRef div has been rendered.